# How to move first element of the JSON object to the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have the JSON like this:

```
[
  "supplier" : "Apple",
  "features" : {
      "0": [
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bbfca0873",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd966f52093ce32f",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }
      ],
      "1":[
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bb33422087",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd91ads2jfloice32",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }

      ]
  },
  "supplier" : "Orange",
  "features" : {
      "0": [
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bbfca0873",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd966f52093ce32f",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }
      ],
      "1":[
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bb33422087",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd91ads2jfloice32",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }

      ]
  }
]
```

How can I use jQuery/javascript to move the features object key '0' to the end after the key '0'? I have tried to use the array.push(array.shift()); but it throws error saying "array.shift()" is not a function. I guess the .features is not array, so how can I move the object to the end?

Comment: Did you mean to say "to the end after key '1'" instead of "to the end after key '0'"?

Comment: That is correct features is actually an object with keys names "0","1",..

Comment: post what you've tried (your code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that features is an object instead of an array? 
You could do something like:

```
"features" : [
      [
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bbfca0873",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd966f52093ce32f",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bb33422087",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd91ads2jfloice32",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }
      ]
  }
```

without problem if you just planned on using numbers as keys. Otherwise, you can get an array of the objects keys (In your case "1", "2", ...) with `Object.keys(features)` and reference the object when needed using those.

Comment: Hi thank Dan, I have just change the objects to array by remove the index key. Now I am able to use the shift().

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

**Swap using a temporary variable**

```
var data = {

  "supplier" : "Apple",
  "features" : {
      "0": [
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bbfca0873",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd966f52093ce32f",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }
      ],
      "1":[
        {
          "feature_id": "58d1b42ec2ef165bb33422087",
          "symbol": "tick"
        },
        {
          "feature_id": "58d4b843bd91ads2jfloice32",
          "symbol": "cross"
        }

      ]
  }
  };


function swap(obj,index1,index2){
    var temp = obj[index1];
    obj[index1] = obj[index2];
    obj[index2] = temp;
    return obj;
}

data.features = swap(data.features,"0","1");
```

// now features["0"] <==> features["1"];